# Ros/Ros2 install failing maybe due to dependencies

Tags: windows, ubuntu, raspbian, ros, ros2

I have extensively tried the link

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Crystal/Windows-Install-Binary/#id3

only for it to fail many, many times. The same with other Ros and Ros2 install guides I could find. I tried searching for solutions at every point of failure and could not find any that worked. Both Ros and Ros2 have failed to install on Windows, Ubuntu 18 and 20, or Raspbian.

Many of the install attempt failed due to dependencies issues, and I have been unable to track down the missing things or otherwise get them to be correctly recognized as available for Ros or Ros2.

If anyone has successfully installed Ros or Ros2, I would like to ask them about it and here details of what worked for them.

Comment: We cannot help to figure out what the problem is without you showing us what error message you received at what step.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the commands step by step following with the document, the ROS shoul be installed correctly. But if your network is poor, the download of some packages will be timeout, it will cause the missing of dependencies. BTW, it is important that you need to run the commands with administrator account.